# ASP.Net RegularExpressionValidator fires if string contains \n or is longer than 250 chars

Tags: asp.net, regex

What is the regular expression for a RegularExpressionValidator so it fires if the string in the validated control contains a \n, \t or is longer then 250 chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^\n\t]{0,250}$
```